# Facebook sdk link or copy to folder

Tags: ios, facebook

Not sure if I'm missing something... The facebook tutorial asks you to drag in the facebook framework from the installed location in documents. However they specifically say don't copy into bundle, just link.

If thats the case, when you archive the app the framework wont be there correct? Are they mistaken or is this reasonable? Also it requires that you install the sdk in everyone of your development computers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link framework as shown in the image

[image]